# Yehi ratzon for the rebuilding of the Temple

Tags: tefilla, minhag, korbanos-ketores-prayers

It is a common Ashkenazi minhag to say a *Yehi ratzon* for the rebuilding of the Temple. The text is based on the words inserted between the two quotes of *Yehuda ben Teima* in [Pirkei Avot 5:10](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94_%D7%9B):

> :יְהִי רָצוֹן מִלְּפָנֶיךָ ה' אֱלֹהֵינוּ שֶׁתִּבְנֶה עִירְךָ בִּמְהֵרָה בְיָמֵינוּ וְתֵן חֶלְקֵנוּ בְּתוֹרָתֶךָ

To this we add the known phrase:

> :וְשָׁם נַעֲבָדְךָ בְּיִרְאָה כִּימֵי עוֹלָם וּכְשָׁנִים קַדְמוֹנִיוֹת

While the last part is from [Malakhi 3:4](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2403.htm#4):

> :וְעָֽרְבָה֙ לַֽיהוָ֔ה מִנְחַ֥ת יְהוּדָ֖ה וִירֽוּשָׁלִָ֑ם כִּימֵ֣י עוֹלָ֔ם וּכְשָׁנִ֖ים קַדְמֹֽנִיֹּֽת

This very last phrase is said after *Elokai netzor,* but not after the *Korbanot* in the morning. Why?

I checked the Machzor Vitry, and the order was quite different back then. The manuscript brings the [tamid offering](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0428.htm), then the words of [Malakhi](http://www.bl.uk/manuscripts/Viewer.aspx?ref=add_ms_27200_f029r), then [Eizehu mekoman](http://mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h51.htm), then the Baraita of Rabbi Yishmael. After this it returns to [Leolam yehei adam](http://www.bl.uk/manuscripts/Viewer.aspx?ref=add_ms_27200_f030r), and right before Barukh Sheamar [only the first part](http://www.bl.uk/manuscripts/Viewer.aspx?ref=add_ms_27200_f030v) is said.

Emden writes only the first part after the Baraita in this edition from [Altona (~1745)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22431&st=&pgnum=166). However, in this later edition from [Warsaw (1881)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42760&st=&pgnum=81) the second part was added. Heidenheim has all three parts in his machzor from [Rödelheim (1800)](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22094&st=&pgnum=35) without the [ל prefix](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/84706/yehi-ratzon-milfanecha-or-lfanecha). But it's not perfectly clear that it was just inserted later, as this [Sulzbach (1701)](https://books.google.it/books?id=jY5CAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP1013) siddur has all three parts present.

Comment: Why do you think Yehuda Ben Tema said that? It seems just like a note at the end of Pikei Avot. It's not actually part of the Mishna

Comment: @DoubleAA Indeed it's not perfectly sure, but it's not at the end of the chapter, and the next section is attributed to him as well, so I had no reason to think it otherwise. If you have a source for the contrary, please share it with me.

Comment: It is not only the end of the chapter, it's the end of the Masekhet. The later stuff is just extra Beraita. Compare with the ending of Taanit and Tamid.

Comment: @DoubleAA I knew that the last chapter was an addition, but I didn't that the end of the fifth was as well. I get your point with a _general optimistic ending,_ but why were the second part of Yehuda ben Teima, Bag Bag and He He not added to the sixth? Are there any commentators discussing this?

Comment: Probably no one can say for sure. See too https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/40801/759

Comment: In Nusach Chabad the second line is not added in, be it after the _Korbanos_ in the morning or after _Elokai Netzor_.